# PS3 controller right analog stick with Cinemachine FreeLook

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I'm trying to set up the right analog stick to move the camera with Cinemachine FreeLook.

Please see the images for my settings.

Currently, when I move the stick up/down, the camera moves left/right.
When I move the stick left/right, nothing happens.

All the guides I've seen seem to have the same settings as I do (4th, 5th axis etc). What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: give a favor new input system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @oistikbal's comment, installed the new input system (from Window >  Package Manager), and then followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=we4CGmkPQ6Q&ab_channel=samyam) tutorial. Right stick now works as expected.